# having trouble running Linux commands in java

Tags: java, linux, command-line, terminal

why I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at com.terminal.Main.main(Main.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 6 more
```

here's the code I'm using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd ~/");
Process pwd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd");
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pwd.getInputStream())) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

and also when I try to execute some other commands such as `sudo` or `./` , `IOException` occurs again...
what is the problem? any idea guys?

thanks :)

Comment: You need an interpreter (shell) to run *cd* command. *cd* itself is not an executable program.

Answer (score 0):

As agad mentioned, cd is not a program, it's a shell command. To change the working directory for your exec() call, use the [three argument method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29):

```
try {
    File wd = new File("~/");
    Process pwd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd", null, wd);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pwd.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

As you may have noticed, this code still returns an error because the use of a tilde as a reference to the home directory is another shell benefit. You can either replace "~/" with the home directory, or in the more likely case that it is unknown, you can use the following code to get the directory:

```
try {
    String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File wd = new File(homedir);
    Process pwd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd", null, wd);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pwd.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you intend to run multiple commands like this, I advise you to follow the above link and attempt to use one of the other methods which has support for multiple commands.